# Clojure: #object[map] is not a function, but its type is a function

Tags: clojurescript, react-final-form

So i'm trying to implement react final form array-field in clojure. I look up in the [example](https://codesandbox.io/s/kx8qv67nk5?file=/index.js) from the document which is written in javascript. I almost got it, but when I tried to use fields.map it said map is not a function even though its type is a function.
Here is my clojure code.

```
(defn field-array [props]
  (fn [{:keys [name validate type]}]
    [:> FieldArray {:name name}
     (fn [props]
       (let [{:keys [fields]} (js->clj props :keywordize-keys true)]
         (print (:map fields))
         (.map fields (fn [k v] (print k)))))]))
```

This is what error said

```
Uncaught TypeError: fields.map is not a function
```

when I print (:map fields)

```
#object[map]
```

Comment: Why not use clojures `map`? Or `run!` to force it.

Comment: I'm not a cljs expert, but I don't think the value in `(:map fields)` is at all related to what happens when you call `(.map fields ...)`. Keyword lookups are a totally different thing from object properties.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find the answer to my own question. it seems like I can't call javascript function via clojurescript for some reason. So instead of converting javascript to clojure like this line.

```
let [{:keys [fields]} (js->clj props :keywordize-keys true)]
```

I must directly call javascript function via passed props like this

```
(.. props -fields -map)
```

hope it helps someone who's struggling with this problem like me.